# Excel macro to apply format to penultimate row of selected range

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a macro to add formatting to a selected range of cells. (Excel 2007) The number of columns and rows of the selected range are always different.  Also the selected areas are not always on the same worksheet.

I recorded a macro and made some minor changes to the code, but I was unable to figure out how I could apply formatting to the cells of the penultimate row of the selected range, which would be in this case double underline borders.

```
Sub feladat()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.CutCopyMode = False
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .Weight = xlThin
End With

Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23).Select
Selection.Font.Bold = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I've tried finding the penultimate row using offset, but with no luck since after running the macro the active cell is always located at a different place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, just some advice: if you really need to apply your format on the selection, it'ok to use `.Select`. But first thing you should learn on VBA: Selections and Activations are to be avoided in order to write a good and efficient code.

Anyway to obtain a selection of the penultimate row in a selected range, you can use a simple pair of commands:

```
TheRow = Selection.Rows.Count-1 + Selection(1).Row
With Workbooks("NameOfYourWorkbook").Worksheets("NameOfYourWorksheet").Rows(TheRow)
    ' Your formatting here WITHOUT writing Selection
    ' For example: .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
End With
```

This will get the number of rows in your selection and subtract 1. Then add the row of the first cell, so you get a clear absolute row address. 
Done that, you can apply your formatting. This doesn't need new selections too.

Comment: I adjusted the code a bit, to work on any worksheet of the workbook and also put "-2"  after  Selection.Rows.Count, but otherwise this works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try This to find and apply format  to Penultimate row
 Before running your macro select the range.
Edit

```
Sub NewMacro()
ShtNm = ActiveSheet.Name
Var = Split(Selection.Address, "$")
 Rwcnt = Var(UBound(Var))
 NewRng = Var(1) & (Rwcnt-1) & ":" & Var(3) & (Rwcnt-1)
Sheets(ShtNm).Range(NewRng).Select 
Call feladat 'Call your function
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but unfortunately it did not work properly. Your macro found the Penultimate row, but also selected cells outside the original selection. (probably because there are other data in the columns).  After the selection it had called my original macro, but then it was executed on the new selected range and not on the original.

Comment: I will edit the original post, as I did not mention that the selected areas are not on the same worksheets.

Comment: I have edited according to your logic. Check it out.